# How to align two arrays with different length in Python (using NaNs where there is no matching element)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array y that contains values observed at given day of the month. The day of the month are in the array x.

I need to interpolate these values using cubic spline so that I can have a value for every day in the month. In order to consider every day in the month I am creating an array xd.

If I want to plot the original y and the interpolated y (i.e. yd), I need them to be aligned on the same axis. This axis is the one considering all day of the month, xd.

Is there an efficient way to quickly create a new array of y which contains exactly the original y element at the right place based on the new x axis, with all other elements filled with zero or NaN (preferably)?

So for example, my first y is only available on day 2, so in the new y array I need the first element to show 0/NaN. Then the second element will show the original y=11, the third will show NaN, etc.

I have written this code which does what I am mentioning above, but I don't know if there is a better/faster way to achieve this. In many situations, the arrays are much bigger than what I am showing in the example below, so having some efficient algorithm would help. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as sp

x = [2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 19, 23, 25, 30]
y = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]

xd = np.linspace(0, max(x), int(max(x))+1) # create the new x axis
ipo = sp.splrep(x, y, k=3) # cubic spline
yd = sp.splev(xd, ipo) # interpolated y values

newY = np.zeros((1, len(yd)), dtype=float) # preallocate for the filled y values

for i in x: 
    if(i in xd): 
        idx, = np.where(xd == i) # find where the original x value is in the new x axis
        idx2, = np.where(np.array(x) == i)
        newY[0, int(idx)] = y[int(idx2)] # replace the y value of the new vector with the y value from original set
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the need to have an aligned set of arrays (that both share the same axis) is because when I plot the two arrays (newY and yd) I also add some subplot where I take the absolute and relative differences to look how good is the fit.

I know in this case the spline will always pass through all the points I give as input so the differences will be zero, but the plotting function below is supposed to work with any kind of comparison (i.e. any kind of interpolated values vs real input). The plotting function I use is the below:

```
def plotInterpolatedVsReal(xaxis, yaxis1, yaxis2, xlab='Dates', mainTitle='', width=25, zero2nan=True):
    if(zero2nan):
        yaxis1[yaxis1 == 0] = np.nan
        yaxis2[yaxis2 == 0] = np.nan

    fix, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 10))
    ax1.plot(xaxis, yaxis1, label='Interpolated')
    ax1.plot(xaxis, yaxis2, 'ro', label='Input')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Prices')
    ax1.legend(loc=0)
    ax2.bar(xaxis, yaxis1 - yaxis2, width=width)
    ax2.axhline(y=0, linewidth=1, color='k')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Errors [diff]')
    ax3.bar(xaxis, 100*(yaxis1/yaxis2 - 1), width=width)
    ax3.axhline(y=0, linewidth=1, color='k')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Errors [%]')
    ax3.set_xlabel(xlab);
    plt.suptitle(mainTitle)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Adding the performance measures for the proposal so far. My loop (method A) is faster because it loops only over the x vector, while other 2 methods loop over xd, which can be considerably larger. In my case here, x has 23 elements while xd has 3655 elements.

```
def A():
    for i in x: 
        if(i in xd): 
            idx, = np.where(xd == i) # find where the original x value is in the new x axis
            idx2, = np.where(np.array(x) == i)
            newY[int(idx)] = y[int(idx2)] # replace the y value of the new vector with the y value from original set 

def B():
    for i, date in enumerate(xd):
        if date in x:
            new_y[i] = date

def C(): 
    known_values = dict(zip(x, y))

    for i,u in enumerate(xd):
        if u in known_values:
            newY[i] = known_values[u]
```

%timeit A()
219 µs ± 8.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit B()
8.87 ms ± 95.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit C()
408 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

I have also tried to pass my A() function to Numba for a JIT compilation:

```
A_nb = numba.jit(A)
```

getting:

%timeit A_nb()
226 µs ± 610 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the point of all this is to plot y values on the same graph, why not doing it directly ?
Axes can handle different x-axis on a same plot easily like so :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 19, 23, 25, 30]
y = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]

xd = np.linspace(0, max(x), int(max(x)) + 1)  # create the new x axis
ipo = sp.splrep(x, y, k=3)  # cubic spline
yd = sp.splev(xd, ipo)  # interpolated y values

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='Original')
ax.plot(xd, yd, label='Interpolated')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

As you wanted, each 'y' data is aligned with it's own x-axis , without having to do any pre-processing. The only interpolation done here is the one Matplotlib does for display purposes.

Since you really need to pad your array with Nan, here is a working way to do it :

```
new_y = np.NAN * np.zeros(yd.shape)
for i, date in enumerate(xd):
    if date in x:
        new_y[i] = date
```

Which can probably be reduced in some fancy one liner

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I added some more details as to why I might still need to have an actual aligned array.

Comment: Looks like your loop is taking longer than mine when the array is of 3655 elements? 0.02 vs 0.001
I am timing is putting start_time = time.time() before the loop and then
 print("total time taken this loop: ", time.time() - start_time)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I completely misunderstand your code, but is `np.linspace(0, max(x), int(max(x))+1)` not simply a roundabout way of writing `np.array(range(1+max(x)))`? It looks as though you're just taking `1+max(x)` linearly spaced samples in a range between `0` and `max(x)` inclusively, which is the same as just taking the integers between 0 and max(x).

And in that case, is it necessary to do this?

```
if(i in xd): 
    idx, = np.where(xd == i) # find where the original x value is in the new x axis
```

If xd is truly just a list of integers from 0 to max(x) inclusive, then all elements in `x` will be in `xd` by definition, and `idx` should always be equal to `i`.

(This assumes that `x` contains only non-negative integer values, of course.)

```
xd = np.array(range(1+max(x)))
newY = np.zeros(len(xd))

for i,j in zip(x, y):
    newY[i] = j
```

Edit: In the more general case where the new axis is not simply the integer range 0..max(x), I would suggest iterating over the array instead, after turning your known values into a dictionary. This would be more efficient, as a linear search is replaced by a dictionary lookup.

```
known_values = dict(zip(x, y))

xd = [... your new axis ...]
newY = np.zeros(len(xd))

for i,x in enumerate(xd):
    if x in known_values:
        newY[i] = known_values[x]
```

Edit: It's interesting that the performance is that much worse - it obviously does happen if the known values are few enough (then looping through the big array is much more expensive) but I thought this wouldn't be a problem in practice.

There's another way of looping that takes advantage of both orderings, but it replaces the np.where with an explicit loop, and I'm not sure if it's actually more efficient, depending on how well the native numpy code is optimized:

```
k = 0
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    while k < len(xd) and xd[k] < i:
        k += 1
    if xd[k] == i:
        newY[k] = j
```

Comment: Yes this is true, but I was trying to address a more general case. For example it could be possible that my new x array xd does not contains all the values in x (maybe just because when building the vector of equally spaced numbers most of them are not intergers corresponding exactly the original x).

Comment: yd is the array of interpolated values. Why are you replacing that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant newY here.

Comment: Even this solution is about 2x slower than my loop. I guess it is because you are looping through the whole new vector xd, while I only focus on the x, which are the times that I care about (and for which I need the corresponding y to be updated in newY).

Comment: Thanks for the update; I've written a third approach that should be better.

Comment: For this approach now is 809 µs ± 9.43 µs per loop

Comment: Btw I am very surprised that there is no benefit when using Numba... Maybe I am doing something wrong there?